# How am I supposed to specify input variables running a procedure in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQLDeveloper I can see a list of procedures and (in theory) run them:

[image]

It lists the parameters but nowhere can I see a way to enter them. If I just click "OK" it appears to try running the procedure with all arguments NULL.

It seems a really useful tool rather than having to write `CALL ...` scripts if I could understand how to use the darn thing!

Comment: You just edit the PL/SQL Block in the bottom section.

Comment: Your screenshot is strange; the Parameters pane (top right of your image), on my copy of SQL Developer, has a fourth column, INPUT VALUE. Not sure why it's missing from yours.

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: @mathguy yeah it confuses me too! Running 3.0.04

Comment: @Mr.Boy - the 'input value' boxes Kris refers to seem to be there in all versions from at least 4.0.3 (can't check back before then), so really the answer is indeed to upgrade if you can. [You can download the latest version here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Basically just where you see the spots for the values edit it.

In the Parameter section, edit the Input Value
or in the PL/SQL Block generated, edit the text directly.

[image]

Comment: I wanna say we updated that screen to include the feature, so they might need to upgrade.

Comment: My version doesn't have an "Input Value" column, but I hadn't realised it just spat out some code... I was hoping to be able to step in to the code.

Comment: upgrade !  The current is 17.4 but even in the older ones you can just edit the block below.

Comment: Good grief I'd no idea we were so far behind!

Comment: Not *that* far, though; version jumped from 4.2 to 17.2 in a single step.

Comment: He's on 3.0.04 which was 2011 so yeah a couple years out of date :)